# Basic Authentication login convert jquery to php code

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I have some document and sample code with jquery Basic Authentication login sample code. I need the php code for my project

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://loginurl',
  headers: {accept:'text/xml'}, //veya "text/json"
  contentType: 'application/json',
  method: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('test' + ':' + 'test'));
  },
  success: function (data) {
    //success
  },
  error: {
    //error
  }
});
```

I tried to convert php like this but I can't login at

```
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";
$remote_url = 'http://loginurl';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")                 
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
```

What's wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: What's wrong? We have no idea because you haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: @miken32 my php code gives connection timeout so not logined i don't understand actualy jquery works file but i need correct php code. thanks for your interest